# Encontrar arquivo no servidor

Tags: php, arquivo

Boa tarde, tenho um arquivo PHP que procura um txt para pegar as informações e subir no banco de dados SQL, porém esse arquivo é gerado pelo servidor aqui da empresa (onde minha máquina já está mapeada para `R:` ou \servidor\adm).

Hoje eu tenho que ir no `R:`, pegar esse arquivo (`ATUALIZA.TXT`), trazer para minha máquina na pasta do WAMP, onde está o arquivo PHP, e aí eu rodo o arquivo.

Porém queria deixar isso "automático", onde o meu programa PHP já procurasse no servidor diretamente sem precisar de eu jogar na minha máquina.

Hoje utilizo o `fopen` (`ATUALIZA.txt`, `r`)", para abrir o arquivo, e funciona normalmente. Estou recebendo este erro quando utilizo o caminha do servidor: `fopen (\\servidor\adm\atualiza.txt):failed to open stream. permission denied in blá blá blá`.

Alguém pode me ajudar a encontrar uma solução em como abrir esse arquivo na rede?? 
Obrigado.

Comment: Já checou se o usuário o qual o PHP esta executando possui acesso a esta pasta do servidor e ao compartilhamento?

Comment: Chequei. Este servidor local é utilizado para compartilhamentos de arquivos internos. Tenho total acesso sobre tal pasta. Possuo permissão para ler, alterar e deletar o arquivo.

Comment: Tem essa página aqui: http://support.ultimatelocator.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/60/0/php-session-problems-warning-session_start-opentmp-failed-permission-denied Verifica se vc seguiu os passos corretamente. As vezes é permissão na pasta, no servidor, ou o caminho da pasta no código. Att,
André.

Answer (score 3):

Perdão não colocar isso como comentário, mas ainda não tenho reputação para tal...

Tive um problema parecido na empresa onde trabalho, onde o PHP criava o arquivo no servidor mas não o criava com as permissões de leitura devidas, a solução que acabei encontrando foi mudar a permissão do arquivo logo após sua geração, com o comando [chmod](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.chmod.php), resolveu meu problema.

**Veja um exemplo:**

```
<?php
// Escrita e leitura para o proprietario, nada ninguem mais
chmod ("/somedir/somefile", 0600);

// Escrita e leitura para o proprietario, leitura para todos os outros
chmod ("/somedir/somefile", 0644);

// Tudo para o proprietario, leitura e execucao para os outros
chmod ("/somedir/somefile", 0755);

// Tudo para o proprietario, leitura e execucao para o grupo do prop
chmod ("/somedir/somefile", 0750);
?>
```

a função `chmod` retorna true ou false, e no teu caso bem podias fazer algo como:

```
<?php
if(chmod("ATUALIZA.TXT", 0644)){
  //instruções para lidar com o ficheiro
  ...
}
?>
```

Outra coisa é, porquê usar `.txt` se existem opções como `JSON` e `XML` ?

Comment: Não consegui utilizar esta função. Acho que pode ser algum problema com a rede, porque se eu fizer com o arquivo local, ele funciona, mas quando insiro o endereço do servidor ele não entende o caminho. O servidor está configurado para que qualquer user utilize os arquivos, permissão total a todos(alterei para realizar os testes)

Comment: A utilização de um ficheiro `.txt` é obrigatório ?
[XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_server.asp) - Ver exemplos.

Answer (score 0):

Como a função `shell_exec()` é muito perigosa para o sistema, aqui vai outra função que pode resolver seu problema.

Pela [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.copy.php), você pode utilizar o comando `copy()`, que ele irá copiar uma fonte para um destino.

```
copy ( 'R:\ATUALIZA.TXT' , 'c:\pata_do_wamp\seu_site\ATUALIZA.TXT' );
```

Comment: credo, porquê usar o `shell_exec` ? Esta é uma função que quando usada acarreta demasiados riscos se não for bem empregue.

Comment: O comando não funcionou pra mim neste caso. Se eu executo o comando pelo DOS ele funciona, copia o arquivo normalmente, mas pelo php ele não faz nada.

Comment: @Edilson como você mesmo disse, ``se não for bem empregue``, creio que este uso não acarretará danos nem riscos ao sistema.

Comment: @Edilson, ficou melhor utilizando a função copy()?

Comment: @MatheusDelatorre se não estou em erro, a função `shell_exec()` é desabilitada por padrão.
E @FranciscoCabral a função `copy()` serve para copiar um arquivo de um destino para outro, e o que o usuário quer, é obter os dados nesse arquivo.

Comment: @Edilson Ele havia dito que conseguia abrir o arquivo se ele movesse manualmente o arquivo para o diretório do site, logo eu procurei a solução mais rápida, copiar o arquivo.